# Why does copying an object's attributes into another one manually updates the view while Object.assign() doesn't?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a parent component, 'EmployeeComponent' that displays a list of employees. And I have a child component, 'EmployeeDetailComponent' that displays the details of a selected employee (name, email etc..).

The selected employee is passed from the parent to the child using @Input like this:

```
@Input() employee: Employee; // This line goes in the child component
```

The child component also allows to edit the information. When edited, the new employee object is then passed to the parent component using an even emitter like this:

In the child component:

```
@Output() onSaved = new EvenEmitter<Employee>();
onSubmit(){
    this.onSaved.emit(this.employee);
}
```

And in the parent component:

```
onSaved(employee: Employee){

    // The line below doesn't affect employee's details in the view
    this.selectedEmployee = Object.assign({}, employee);

    // However, old values are successfully replaced by new ones
    console.log(this.selectedEmployee);

    //And the line below changes successfully the employee's details in the view
    this.employee.name = employee.name;

}
```

So my question is, since in both ways, the employee's details are changed, why does the second way affect the information in the view and not the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign()` returns the same object instance. Angular change detection only checks object identity, but not the objects content when it compares old and new value.

If you have another object, then Angular change detection considers it a change, even when the object contains the same properties with the same values. This causes the view to re-render.

Comment: Oh okay, so in this case how should I do to replace the old values with the new ones? I need to avoid doing it manually and one by one...

Comment: When you use `this.selectedEmployee = Object.assign({}, employee);` where target (first parameter) is a new object, then the result should be a new object. You basically create a clone this way, then change detection will recognize the change. If you use `this.selectedEmployee = Object.assign(oldEmpl, newEmpl);`, then `oldEmpl` stays the same object and only it's content is modified.